# How to give input for the double[] array in Java

Tags: java

How do I give input directly, when that function is invoked in another method, especially when that input is a `double[]` array?

```
public double dotPro1(double[] vectorA, double[] vectorB) {
    double[] vecPro;
    vecPro = new double[2];
    vecPro[0] = vectorA[0]*vectorB[0];
    vecPro[1] = vectorA[1]*vectorB[1];
    return vecPro[0] + vecPro[1];
}
public double dotPro2(double[] length) {
    double[] lenPro;
    lenPro = new double[1];
    lenPro[0] = length[0];
    return lenPro[0];
}
public static double cosine(double a) {
    double x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(a));
    /*Class c = Class.forName("NaiveStrategy");
        Class methodTypes[] = new Class[3];
        methodTypes[0] = Double.TYPE;
        methodTypes[1] = Double.TYPE;
        methodTypes[2] = Double.TYPE;
        Method[] m = c.getMethods();*/
    NaiveStrategy ns = new NaiveStrategy();
  problem-->ns.dotPro1(vectorA[], vectorB[]);
  problem-->ns.dotPro2(length[]);
    return 0;  
}
```

As you can also see my old coding I tried in another way to solve it, but it didn't worked. It's commented out above.

Comment: At which place are you facing the problem..can u pin point it

Comment: Why isn't `dotPro2` just `{ return length[0]; }`? What's with all the useless `double[]` manipulation?

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra, i have pinpointed my problem.

Comment: @basiljames, actually its not useful, i need an array of values to getValues for the length that is magnitude of the vectors in double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in one comment that you want random values. So use the Random class to generate them.

```
double[] list1 = new double[5];
double[] list2 = new double[5];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    list1[i] = rand.nextDouble();
}

for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
    list2[i] = rand.nextDouble();
}
```

The new double[5]; will create an array of length 5. Change this number to the length you want.

Note: rand.nextdouble only gives a random number between 0 and 1. If you wish it to , say, be between 0 and 100 then use rand.nextDouble()*100

You can then just use

```
double result1 = ns.dotPro1(list1, list2);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not at all clear what you mean - but certainly the syntax you've got at the moment won't work. If you're just looking to create an array at execution time, that's easy:

```
NaiveStrategy ns = new NaiveStrategy();
// Either using separate variables...
double[] first = { 0.5, 0.1, 10 };
double[] second { 5, 20.3, 1 };
double result1 = ns.dotPro1(first, second);

// Or inline...
double results2 = ns.dotPro2(new double[] { 50.2, 0.3 });
```

I can't tell why you've got commented-out reflection calls in your code though...

Also, as noted in comments, your methods seem to be creating arrays for no particular purpose. They could be rewritten as:

```
public double dotPro1(double[] vectorA, double[] vectorB) {
    return vectorA[0] * vectorB[0] + vectorA[1] * vectorB[1];
}

public double dotPro2(double[] length) {
    return length[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing the array parameter do not put the square braces.

`= ns.dotPro2(length);`
`= ns.dotPro1(vectorA, vectorB);`

Comment: i know i am just showing my problem here. how do i directly assign values for my array here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, as my net went off..... Ok back to the answer...

Here is the simplest way to do it...

```
double[] first = { 0.10, 0.15, 0.30 };
double[] second { 65, 44.3, 10.11 };
double result1 = ns.dotPro1(first, second);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i need runtime input values for arrays

Comment: @so whats the probs in it..you can always input double variables into array during runtime... but i would suggest you to use Collection than going for array..its more flexible..

Comment: actually i am new to java programming! it would be nice if i get answers exactly what i need from you?

Comment: actually the answer u suggested me might help me generating just that declared value inside the braces, but i need random values to be generated.